# How much experience does a guild get per person for a boss kill?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

How much xp does one get for a guild boss kill in cataclysm?  I can't find a guide for this anywhere.

To be more specific: How much guild xp would be gained given the following circumstances?  It makes more sense to record the amount of xp given per person.  That way the amount of guild xp can be extrapolated exactly based on the number of guildies in the run.

- 5 man regular dungeon (24800 xp per person, with guild lvl2)
- 5 man heroic dungeon (37800 xp per person, with guild lvl6)
- 10 man regular raid (27800 xp per person, with guild lvl6)
- 10 man heroic raid
- 25 man regular raid
- 25 man heroic raid

Comment: I think the reason it's so hard to find is more likely that the daily guild XP cap is a very low number, and by the time of day most guilds are killing bosses, people have already done their dailies or leveled their alts or whatever and gotten the guild to cap for the day

Comment: Sadly not true for my guild of about 10 folks.  The achievement xp change alone sucked most of the fun out of guild leveling.  Throw in the quest xp reduction and we'll never see level 25.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All of these assume you were in a guild group. The comp of the guild group doesn't matter (4 or 5 guildies)

- 5 man regular dungeon (24800 xp per person, with guild lvl2)
- 5 man heroic dungeon (37800 xp per person, with guild lvl6)
- 10 man regular raid (27800 xp per person, with guild lvl6)
- 10 man heroic raid
- 25 man regular raid
- 25 man heroic raid

I realize this is incomplete, but it's the best answer so far.  It's from my own in-game experience.  Feel free to comment with your findings and I'll add them here.

Answer (score 5):

The amount of guild experience awarded varies. It is depended on specific factors... ([***Source***](http://www.wowpedia.org/Guild_advancement))

#### Guild xp for boss kills is scaled on a few factors.

- Boss level
- Normal / Heroic
- Amount of guild members present (more xp for raids, since they are limited to once a week)

  - 20/25 - 25 player raid
  - 8/10 - 10 player raid,
  - 3/5 - dungeons
  - 8/25 - Old 25 and 40 man raids (Vanilla, TBC, and WOTLK)

#### Straight from Blizzard's Mouth *([Source](http://us.battle.net/wow/en/blog/2113741))*

> The amount of experience gained scales, with 3/5 guild members granting 50% normal guild xp, 4/5 giving 100%, and 5/5 giving 125% guild xp. The amount gained from each boss scales with your level relative to the boss's level, with Heroic bosses worth even more (1.5x). It pays off to have a full group of guild members!

Comment: This doesn't actually answer the question at all.

Comment: What part of, _The amount of guild experience awarded varies. It is depended on specific factors..._ doesn't answer the question? It **varies**. Meaning there isn't a set amount. If he provide the details of situation other than asking generally what a guild will get for downing any boss, then I might have tailored my answer the situation. Until then the I have provide is the closest you will get to answer it.

Comment: Along with my answer, also provide what it depends on.

Comment: My question is now more specific.

Comment: Lots of numbers in WoW vary and depend on a variety of factors. But there are rules and formulas to determine them, and a complete answer could include those rules (if they are known).

Comment: which most are an educated guess and rarely are they known as a fact...

Answer (score 0):

It varies by level of boss and yourself, just like xp.

You will get level 25 in a about a honest year, just like everyone else. Adding more people to the guild helps with days where people might not all be online. That's about it.

Comment: I figured it varied, but surely there's some consistent number for heroic dungeon, non-heroic dungeon, raid, heroic raid.

Comment: Sadly that's just not how xp works for bosses and especially raids.